# Access TextView from Fragment to Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, textview, fragment

[image]

Number 1. Call Fragment1 with Button Event

Number 2. Express the called fragment in Layout1

Number 3. When Button 1 is pressed with Fragment1 called in Layout 1, Fragment2 calls to Layout 2

Number 4. If you press the Back button while Fragment 2 is called, Layout only returns to the screen with the original Button 1, Button 2.

It doesn't have to be this way.
What I want is If other Fragments are open, you want to press BackButton to return to the default Fragment with Button 1 and Button 2.

Or

Title Fragment and ChoiceButtonFragment
We make them separately. And I want to access TitleFragment's TextView from ChoiceButtonFragment.
That is, I want direct access from Fragment to Fragment without any activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Access TextView By Following Way In The Fragment

```
  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);
var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.MyTextView); }
```